# Issue in running Apache Superset

Tags: python-3.x, flask-login

I am trying to run superset locally. after installing i got this error.

**superset run -p 8088 --with-threads --reload --debugger
Usage: superset [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...**

Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

step 1:
set FLASK_APP=superset
superset fab create-admin

step 2: Load some data to play with
superset load_examples

step 3: Create default roles and permissions
superset init

step 4: To start a development web server on port 8088
superset run -p 8088 --with-threads --reload --debugger